# Open another ContextMenu when clicked on first ContextMenu's Item

Tags: android, contextmenu

```
registerForContextMenu(validate_button);
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        menu.add("It's right");
        menu.add("It's wrong");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        //i want to show another Context Menu to select next answer
        return true;
    }
```

How to show another `ContextMenu` when I click an item of the first `ContextMenu`?.

Its something like a questioner where you select answers from the `ContextMenu` items, depending on which next `ContextMenu` items must be Populated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to show another ContextMenu when i click an Item of the 1st
>   ContextMenu??

I don't know how deep you want the `ContextMenu` to be but for two levels you could have a boolean flag, to select between the two cases, which will be updated from `onContextItemSelected`:

```
boolean flag = true;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (flag) {
       menu.add("It's right");
       menu.add("It's wrong");
    } else {
       // the second menu
       menu.add("Ha Ha");
    }
}
```

Then in the `onContexItemSelected` callback simply update the flag and post a Runnable to show the `ContextMenu` again:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       if (item.getItemId() == theIdOfItemFromSecondContextMenu) {
        // do stuff
        return true;
    }
    // if you pass at this level, then you need to show the second ContextMenu
    flag = false;
    theView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            theView.showContextMenu();
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Anyway, I would advise against such code and simply use a custom `Dialog`(or a `DialogFragment` to have a backstack for the user to cycle through).

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Yes, a simple mistake.

Comment: and but again when i click on the item of 2nd ContextMenu, it will again trigger the onContextItemSelected and will open the 2nd menu again?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc If you use the `item.getItemId`(and set different ids for the second level items) you'll know at what level you are. See my edited answer.

Comment: @RavindMaurya `theView` is a reference to the `View` for which you open the menu.

Comment: Your answer helped me. But have a query to ask, why your make this as a separate thread.?   theView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            theView.showContextMenu();
        }
    });

Comment: @CHAKRAVARTHI The question is old and I don't remember why I used that runnable(and if it's really necessary). Also, it isn't another thread it's just a method to delay that piece of code(in this case showing the menu) to be run in the future.